# Ken Burns effect stutters on Microsoft Edge (Divi theme, fullwidth slider)

Tags: css, animation, slider

I have an issue with my Ken Burns effect on Microsoft Edge which makes it stuttery although it works perfectly on chrome and I wonder if someone could help me tweaking my code, thanks a lot in advance!
Link to the website :  frama.link/9UQ_8sTd
CSS code :

```
.kb-zoomout .et_pb_slide .et_parallax_bg {
   animation: zoomout 7s forwards;
  -ms-animation: zoomout 7s forwards;
  -webkit-animation: zoomout 7s forwards;
  -0-animation: zoomout 7s forwards;
  -moz-animation: zoomout 7s forwards;


}

.kb-zoomin .et_pb_slide .et_parallax_bg {
   animation: zoomin 7s forwards;
  -ms-animation: zoomin 7s forwards;
  -webkit-animation: zoomin 7s forwards;
  -0-animation: zoomin 7s forwards;
  -moz-animation: zoomin 7s forwards;

}

.kb-zoomin-right .et_pb_slide .et_parallax_bg {
   animation: zoomin-right 7s forwards;
  -ms-animation: zoomin-right 7s forwards;
  -webkit-animation: zoomin-right 7s forwards;
  -0-animation: zoomin-right 7s forwards;
  -moz-animation: zoomin-right 7s forwards;

}

.kb-zoomout-right .et_pb_slide .et_parallax_bg {
   animation: zoomout-right 7s forwards;
  -ms-animation: zoomout-right 7s forwards;
  -webkit-animation: zoomout-right 7s forwards;
  -0-animation: zoomout-right 7s forwards;
  -moz-animation: zoomout-right 7s forwards;

}

.kb-zoomout .et_parallax_bg {
   animation: zoomout 17s forwards;
  -ms-animation: zoomout 17s forwards;
  -webkit-animation: zoomout 17s forwards;
  -0-animation: zoomout 17s forwards;
  -moz-animation: zoomout 17s forwards;

}

.kb-zoomin .et_parallax_bg {
   animation: zoomin 17s forwards;
  -ms-animation: zoomin 17s forwards;
  -webkit-animation: zoomin 17s forwards;
  -0-animation: zoomin 17s forwards;
  -moz-animation: zoomin 17s forwards;

}

.kb-zoomin-right .et_parallax_bg {
   animation: zoomin-right 7s forwards;
  -ms-animation: zoomin-right 17s forwards;
  -webkit-animation: zoomin-right 17s forwards;
  -0-animation: zoomin-right 17s forwards;
  -moz-animation: zoomin-right 17s forwards;

}

.kb-zoomout-right .et_parallax_bg {
   animation: zoomout-right 7s forwards;
  -ms-animation: zoomout-right 17s forwards;
  -webkit-animation: zoomout-right 17s forwards;
  -0-animation: zoomout-right 17s forwards;
  -moz-animation: zoomout-right 17s forwards;

}



@keyframes zoomout{
0% {
    -ms-transform: scale3d(1.5, 1.5, 1.5) translate3d(-0px, 0px, 0px);
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(1.5, 1.5, 1.5) translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
    -o-transform: scale3d(1.5, 1.5, 1.5) translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
    -moz-transform: scale3d(1.5, 1.5, 1.5) translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
    transform: scale3d(1.5, 1.5, 1.5) translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
    animation-timing-function: linear;
}


100% {
    -ms-transform: scale3d(1.1, 1.1, 1.1) translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(1.1, 1.1, 1.1) translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
    -o-transform: scale3d(1.1, 1.1, 1.1) translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
    -moz-transform: scale3d(1.1, 1.1, 1.1) translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
    transform: scale3d(1.1, 1.1, 1.1) translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);

}
}

@keyframes zoomin{
0%{
    -ms-transform: scale3d(1.1, 1.1, 1.1) translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(1.1, 1.1, 1.1) translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
    -o-transform: scale3d(1.1, 1.1, 1.1) translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
    -moz-transform: scale3d(1.1, 1.1, 1.1) translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
    transform: scale3d(1.1, 1.1, 1.1) translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
    animation-timing-function: linear;


}


100%{
    -ms-transform: scale3d(1.5, 1.5, 1.5) translate3d(-0px, 0px, 0px);
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(3.5, 3.5, 3.5) translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
    -o-transform: scale3d(1.5, 1.5, 1.5) translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
    -moz-transform: scale3d(1.5, 1.5, 1.5) translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
    transform: scale3d(1.5, 1.5, 1.5) translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);

}
}

@keyframes zoomout-right{
0%{
    -ms-transform: scale3d(1.5, 1.5, 1.5) translate3d(-150px, -20px, 0px);
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(1.5, 1.5, 1.5) translate3d(-150px, -20px, 0px);
    -o-transform: scale3d(1.5, 1.5, 1.5) translate3d(-150px, -20px, 0px);
    -moz-transform: scale3d(1.5, 1.5, 1.5) translate3d(-150px, -20px, 0px);
    transform: scale3d(1.5, 1.5, 1.5) translate3d(-150px, -20px, 0px);
    animation-timing-function: linear;
}


100%{
    -ms-transform: scale3d(1.1, 1.1, 1.1) translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(1.1, 1.1, 1.1) translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
    -o-transform: scale3d(1.1, 1.1, 1.1) translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
    -moz-transform: scale3d(1.1, 1.1, 1.1) translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
    transform: scale3d(1.1, 1.1, 1.1) translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);

}
}

@keyframes zoomin-right{
0%{
    -ms-transform: scale3d(1.1, 1.1, 1.1) translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(1.1, 1.1, 1.1) translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
    -o-transform: scale3d(1.1, 1.1, 1.1) translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
    -moz-transform: scale3d(1.1, 1.1, 1.1) translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
    transform: scale3d(1.1, 1.1, 1.1) translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
    animation-timing-function: linear;
}


100%{
    -ms-transform: scale3d(1.5, 1.5, 1.5) translate3d(-150px, -20px, 0px);
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(1.5, 1.5, 1.5) translate3d(-150px, -20px, 0px);
    -o-transform: scale3d(1.5, 1.5, 1.5) translate3d(-150px, -20px, 0px);
    -moz-transform: scale3d(1.5, 1.5, 1.5) translate3d(-150px, -20px, 0px);
    transform: scale3d(1.5, 1.5, 1.5) translate3d(-150px, -20px, 0px);

}
}
```

The site asks me to post more details and less code so I write a little bit here.

Comment: Show us your html code or create snippet, So we are trying to help you! :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, here is the link of the website if it can help : https://frama.link/9UQ_8sTd

Comment: Also here is the article I used to create it : https://intercom.help/elegantthemes/en/articles/2717227-how-to-create-and-use-the-ken-burns-effect-in-divi

Comment: _“here is the link of the website if it can help”_ - please go read  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it and [mre], and then edit your question accordingly.

Comment: 1. Which version of Internet Explorer are we talking about ? 2. It doesn't stutter in Chrome / Firefox & Safari apparently. 3. What have you tried so far ?

Comment: Sorry it's actually on Microsoft Edge that it stutters here is the version : Microsoft Edge 44.18362.449.0

Comment: I only tried it on Chrome and Edge for the moment